# JavaScript countdown in random increments

Tags: javascript

i have spend an hour trying to find such a script to no avail

I want a simple countdown that starts at 200 units and decreases by a random increment between 0-3 units every second

Comment: What is your question? This sounds like "someone else do this thing for me", not a question =D

Comment: **HINT:** Use `Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
var count = 200;
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    count -= Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
    if( count <= 0) {
        count = 0;
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
},1000);
```

Comment: Well, given that I learn by looking at and understanding other people's code, yes it should.

Comment: Add in a line to show it, maybe `element.innerHTML = count;` or something like that.

Comment: var count = 200;
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    count -= Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
    if( count <= 0) {
        count = 0;
        clearInterval(timer);
document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = --timer;
    }
},1000);
</script>

Comment: Not quite. The `--timer` is unnecessary and not the right variable anyway - it's `count` you want to show. Also this will only display `0` when the timer runs out. Move it out of the `if{}` block.

Comment: <span id="seconds"></span> seconds left.
    <script>
      var seconds = 66;
      setInterval(
        function(){
          document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = --seconds;
        }, 1000
      );
    </script></span><br><br>

Comment: this stackoverlfow board sucks ass..everythign is compressed

Comment: i will pay someone $5 paypal if they can send me a working, html ready countdown with the random factor built in

Comment: Don't worry about it. This time :p